Leaflet map with multiple markers - show tooltip on mouse-over only of the last item in marker list
In my leaflet map I have this code that shows many markers.
I want to get the tooltip shown on mouseover but I get the mouse-over only for the last marker in the list. The other ones shows only on click.
`var markers = [    
    [ 9.39069271, 45.92184121, "Grignetta (2177 metri)" ],
    [ 9.14496, 46.12351, "Pizzo di Gino" ],
    [ 9.14714813, 46.00030059, "Cima di Lenno (1698 metri)" ],    
    ];

//Marker Icon
var spot = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '../_asset/icons/spot.svg',
    iconSize:     [18, 18], // size of the icon
});
         
//Loop through the markers array
    for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
           
    var lon = markers[i][0];
    var lat = markers[i][1];
    var popupText = markers[i][2];
            
    var markerLocation = new L.LatLng(lat, lon);
    var marker = new L.Marker(markerLocation, {icon: spot});
    leafletmap.addLayer(marker);
         
    marker.bindPopup(popupText);
    };

marker.on('mouseover', function (e) {
  this.openPopup();
});
marker.on('mouseout', function (e) {
  this.closePopup();
});`

I tried other solution but this one is the best i came up with.
Any help or hint?

Pal, you're attaching the events outside of the for loop. Seems like you gotta review very basic concepts, like how loops and conditionals work.

oh my.....    Yes....   what a dumb error.  Thank You
